# Conspicuous v. Ostentatious

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Conspicuous means: 1. Easy to notice; obvious: a conspicuous flaw in the construction.
2. Attracting attention, as by being unusual or remarkable; noticeable.

Ostentatious means: characterized by pretentious or showy display; designed to impress.

Both the above words are shown as synonyms to each other, however, I doubt if they are clear synonyms and can be used as replacing words for each other.

Kindly explain with the logic of usage and why or why should not these be used as synonyms to each other?

(*meanings are taken from the web dictionary using google search help)

Comment: How would a conspicuous mistake be considered ostentatious?

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer from the source you cited. Ostentatious involves showing off. Ostentatious is  conspicuous, but conspicuous is not necessarily ostentatious. So you are correct, they overlap but are not exact sunonyms.

Comment: Sunonyms having different shades of meaning?

Comment: Yes, Synonyms with different shades of meaning. 
Would add after my research:- Conspicuous means (1)Either very obvious to the eyes, OR (2)attracting attention(because of striking quality), whereas Ostentatious is disapproving Conspicuous show to impress, show-off of what one already(*refer pretentious v ostentatious)has to attract attention. A deliberately designed effort to attract attention, a flashy show-off of money, power, possessions or knowledge to get attention. Origination- Latin word ostentare, “to display”, But in English often used for displays of crass or vulgar sort.

Answer (score 0):

Would add after my research:- 
Conspicuous means (1)Either very obvious to the eyes, standing out so much that it is noticed right away, OR (2)attracting attention(because of striking quality or feature), 
whereas Ostentatious is disapproving Conspicuous show to impress, show-off of what one already* has to attract attention. A deliberately designed effort to attract attention, vulgar and in bad taste, a flashy show-off of money, power, possessions or knowledge to get attention. Origination- Latin word ostentare, “to display”, But in English often used for displays of crass or vulgar sort.

(*refer pretentious v ostentatious)
Sources: Different dictionaries and thesaurus through on-line search besides the English Oxford Dictionary.